# Create multiple posts with WP REST API at once

Tags: json, rest-api

I managed it to create single posts with a simple JSON object via the WP REST API like...

```
{
  title: "My Title",
  content: "My Content",
  excerpt: "My Excerpt"
}
```

I'm wondering, if there is a way to create multiple posts in one go, like...

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      title: "My title 1",
      content: "My content 1",
      excerpt: "My excerpt 1"
    },
    {
      title: "My title 2",
      content: "My content 2",
      excerpt: "My excerpt 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Couldn't find any information to this. There are only examples to create on post at at time.

Comment: For reference I tried passing post objects in an array ala `[ {},{} ]` but that didn't work either, my suspicion is it isn't supported unless you write custom endpoints, but I'd love to be proven wrong

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking in the moment. I'm afraid, you're right...